# Eclipse JSTL completion: how to make visible new JSTL variables defined by my custom tag

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, taglib, tag-library-descriptor

We've built a custom taglib which declares (via Tag TEI class) a new variable which becomes visible both at script level and JSTLS level.
Eclipse completes correctly the object whitin scriptlets but does not recognize it within JSTL. Are we missing some config in Eclipse? Might it be something within the TLD of the taglib?

here's an example:

```
<w:helper name="myBean" class="com.customer.Example"/>
<%
    myBean.method();    //here the completion works, both invoking ctrl+space on "myB" and "myBean." 
%>
${myBean.field}   // here no completion at all
```

I would like Eclipse to be able to complete on both the lines.

Any help?

***Added info***:

the TLD declares jspversion 1.1
DTD declaration for DTD is http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd

***Edit 2016-10-21***:

- We're using Eclipse Mars.
- We've tested TLD version 2.0 with DTD 2 without success.
- We've also tracked the problem to Eclipse being unable to complete *any* JSP-EL variable. The following example does *not* provide completion.

```html
    
 <c:set var="test">hello</c:set>
 ${te     // here ctrl+space will NOT proposte "test"
 <c:set var="second" value="${te}"/> // here too not working
```

Comment: In order to access bean directly in JSTL you need to set bean using `pageContext.setAttribute()`

Comment: thanks @Arvid we already do it and it works at _runtime_, unfortunately Eclipse does not seem to understand and does not offer completion within the JSP-EL expression :-/